# JSON code beutify getting an error Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'

Tags: json, xml

I have a JSON file I want to beautify the file but getting this error.

I tried by removed `<!CDATA` also and add the string `"a:5"` but unable to achieve.

```
Parse error on line 1:
<![CDATA[a:5:{s:5:"w
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

I was tried in [Online JSON format](https://jsonformatter.org/)

Can help me out this error. Below is my file data

`<![CDATA[a:5:{s:5:"width";i:1000;s:6:"height";i:750;s:4:"file";s:35:"2017/03/jens-oliver-meiert-1313.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:9:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"jens-oliver-meiert-1313-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"jens-oliver-meiert-1313-300x225.jpg";s:5:"width";i:300;s:6:"height";i:225;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:12:"medium_large";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"jens-oliver-meiert-1313-768x576.jpg";s:5:"width";i:768;s:6:"height";i:576;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:29:"test-image-350x204-croped";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"jens-oliver-meiert-1313-350x204.jpg";s:5:"width";i:350;s:6:"height";i:204;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:29:"test-image-350x250-croped";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"jens-oliver-meiert-1313-350x250.jpg";s:5:"width";i:350;s:6:"height";i:250;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:30:"test-image-1110x550-croped";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:36:"jens-oliver-meiert-1313-1000x550.jpg";s:5:"width";i:1000;s:6:"height";i:550;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:27:"test-image-50x50-croped";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:33:"jens-oliver-meiert-1313-50x50.jpg";s:5:"width";i:50;s:6:"height";i:50;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:29:"test-image-255x182-croped";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"jens-oliver-meiert-1313-255x182.jpg";s:5:"width";i:255;s:6:"height";i:182;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:29:"test-image-350x195-croped";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:35:"jens-oliver-meiert-1313-350x195.jpg";s:5:"width";i:350;s:6:"height";i:195;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}]]>`

Comment: Are you sure about that? That does not look like a valid JSON file. Why is there a `CDATA` wrapping?

Comment: I have an XML file inside this JSON data. I just trying to format JSON data.

Comment: Even without the CDATA wrapper it would not be valid JSON. If you can parse the XML into an array format you should be able to convert that to JSON

Comment: @tshimkus Thanks. what will be the solution to this?

Comment: Depends what language you are using.

Comment: @tshimkus I have an XML file inside this the above data is present. I just want to beautify.

Comment: It looks like a WordPress serialized database blob. In php you can use `unserialize()` to get an array, and `var_dump()` to print that array in a readable format.

Comment: @tshimkus It is a WordPress demo import XML file.